# Problems with SPRING 3.0 annotated Controller

Tags: spring-mvc

Hi im new in the spring world so i want to create my own controller using @Controller notation, but i suppose im doing something bad. Anybody can help me???

Here is my dispatch-servlet

```
<bean  Class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>


 <context:component-scan base-package="hibernateTest.web" />

<context:annotation-config/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>


<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

And here is my controller

```
package springapp.web;

import com.sun.msv.reader.Controller;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.logging.Log;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;
import springapp.service.ProductManager;


@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller

public class HelloController {
protected final Log logger = (Log) LogFactory.getLog(getClass()); 
private ProductManager productManager; 


@RequestMapping("/hello.htm")
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response)

        throws ServletException, IOException { 

    String now = (new java.util.Date()).toString();

    logger.info("returning hello view with " + now); 

    Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    myModel.put("now", now);

    myModel.put("products", this.productManager.getProducts()); 

    return new ModelAndView("hello", "model", myModel);

 }}
```

The result of running this is a 404, when The hello.jsp exist

Answer (score 0):

Your controller class is in package `springapp.web`, while in `context:component-scan` you have `base-package` set to `hibernateTest.web`.

Spring cannot detect your controller, because your configuration tells it to search for annotated classes only in `hibernateTest.web` package.

Changing package name in `context:component-scan` should fix this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="springapp.web" />
```

Comment: Ok i fixed that now the error says
El prefijo "context" para el elemento "context:component-scan" no está enlazado.
And continues giving me the 404. The version of Spring is 3.1

Comment: It seems you're missing namespace declaration. This error is `The prefix "context" for element "context: component-scan" is not bound` in English - just google it and try one of SO answers that will come up.